# How to confirm JProfiler agent is attached

Tags: java, performance, jprofiler

I have a application server running and I have attached **JProfiler** jagent to the server so that I can connect a JProfiler GUI and observe the performance. I have added the following to the JVM parameter list

```
-agentpath:/exports/JProfiler/jprofiler8/bin/linux-x64/libjprofilerti.so=port=8849
```

However, when I start my glassfish server, I cannot attach the Jprofiler UI to it. It gives error "Could not connect to :8849. Please make sure that the remote address is correct." The remote ip is indeed correct. How do I know that the application server started with the JVM parameters I mentioned? Is there a way to confirm this?

Comment: You should see in log file startup command with additional parameters you provided, how do you start glassfish ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, look at the stderr output of your application server. There have to be some lines prefixed with `JProfiler>`. If not, the -agentpath VM parameter was not passed to the JVM.

In your specific case, you don't have the "nowait" option appended. This means that the JVM will wait at startup for a connection from the JProfiler GUI. If the application server responds to HTTP requests without that a JProfiler GUI has connected at all, the -agentpath VM parameter was definitely not passed to the JVM.